# What order of growth does a ratio of Bigh-Ohs have?

Tags: asymptotics

Say that $f(n) = \cal O(n^2)$ and $g(n) = \cal O(n)$.

If $h(n)=f(n)/g(n)$,  is it true that $h(n) =\cal O(n)$?

Is it mathematically correct to say that $h(n) = \cal O(n^2)/ O(n) = O(n)$? if not, what would be the correct way to show this?

Comment: Hence we see why you should always [use $\Theta$ when you mean it](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use).

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 9):

Let $f(n)= n^2$ and $g(n)=1$. Then $f(n) = \cal O(n^2)$ and $g(n) = \cal O(n)$.

However, $h(n)=f(n)/g(n)=n^2/1 = n^2 \neq \cal{O}(n)$.

Comment: For an even more extreme example, take $g(n)=n^{-1000000}\;$!